# Restforce Gem - Rails 4 | Retrieving Organisational limits from Salesfroce via API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, salesforce

I've got a working setup using the [Restforce gem](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce). I'm going through the salesforce [Rest API documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm) and trying to work out what I can and can't make calls to through it.

I've spotted one documented feature in [Limits](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm). Specifically I'd like to record our number of 'Daily API calls' and - hopefully log things to drop a use alert if we're getting close to the limit.

But I can't work out how to get the information back.

I see the URI as `/vXX.X/limits/` which made me hope I could use `@restforce.limits` in conjunction with the authentication method below.

```
@restforce = Restforce.new :oauth_token => current_user.oauth_token,
                 :refresh_token => current_user.refresh_token,
                 :instance_url  => current_user.instance_url,
                 :client_id     => Rails.application.config.salesforce_app_id,
                 :client_secret => Rails.application.config.salesforce_app_secret
```

Anyone had any success calling limits via restforce?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using at least version 29.0 of the API for limits to work.

```
@restforce = Restforce.new :oauth_token => current_user.oauth_token,
    :refresh_token => current_user.refresh_token,
    :instance_url  => current_user.instance_url,
    :client_id     => Rails.application.config.salesforce_app_id,
    :client_secret => Rails.application.config.salesforce_app_secret,
    :api_version => "29.0"
```

See: https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce#api-versions

and: https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce#limits